# The logout function in my app doesn't work Node.js

Tags: node.js, logout

```
const handleLogout = () => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8800/api/auth/logout")
      .then(() => {
        toast.success("Logout Sucess!");
        // navigate("/");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

```
export const logout = (req, res) => {
  res
    .clearCookie("accessToken", {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    })
    .status(200)
    .json("Logout successful!");
};
```

```
router.post("/logout", logout);
```

Logout doesn't work at all, but it has a strange behavior, because if I put a console.log() in logout it will be perfectly called, it just doesn't manage to clear the cookies for some reason, the no of cookies is perfectly the same as this everything working except clearing cookies

I've tried using other methods like destroy and other types of requests like get but nothing works, in addition to that I changed the name of the cookie and even tried to do it in a different way, calling the cookie and setting its maxAge to 0 but by default it also doesn't it worked

Comment: You can try adding the `withCredentials: true` option to your `axios.post()`.

Comment: Is the `handleLogout()` function in a webpage in a browser?  If so, what is the URL of that webpage (so we can see if this could be a CORs issue).

Comment: Also, ,why are you setting `secure: true` when this is an `http` request, not an `https` request?

Comment: Is a `path` option set on the cookie when it is originally set?

Comment: Where'd you go?  I'm trying to help (before I go to sleep), but you're not responding to my questions.  Since it looks like you're new here, it will be to your advantage to regularly check back here (in the next couple of hours after posting) to see if people have questions about your question.  This is not the same as some online forum where you might post and then come back the next day.  Your question may get closed as "unclear" before you come back.